# How to delay autoplay of 3 sliders by 0.5 seconds respectively?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 slideshows, which were created with [Owl Carousel 2](http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).

I would like to initialize them on page load, but delay autoplay by 0.5 seconds respectively, i.e. the first slideshow starts, the second one waits 0.5 seconds until autoplay starts, the third waits 1 second.

Already thought about writing a function for each slideshow-code and then use `setTimeout()` to delay execution. The problem here is that the markup would not get recognized as a slideshow until the moment of execution, which destroys the layout. The slideshows should be initialized on page load, but autoplay delayed.

Here is my code so far:

```
$('.carousel01').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    smartSpeed: 300,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    nav: false,
    dots: false
  });

  $('.carousel02').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    smartSpeed: 300,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    nav: false,
    dots: false
  });

  $('.carousel03').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    smartSpeed: 300,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    nav: false,
    dots: false
  });
```

Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: What is effect of `autoplayTimeout` setting?

Comment: ```autoplayTimeout``` is the delay between each slide change (5 seconds). I would like the keep this time the same for all sliders, but just delay the autoplay start.

Comment: Is requirement `.owlCarousel()` to be called at same time, though settings applied after a given duration?

Comment: As I mentioned, if you don't call ```.owlCarousel()``` on page load, the markup of the slideshow is not recognized and destroys the layout. This is fixed once the function is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. here's the final code:

```
// Get the elements
var owl_1 = $('.carousel01');
var owl_2 = $('.carousel02');
var owl_3 = $('.carousel03');

// Apply OWL Carousel
owl_1.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    smartSpeed: 300,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    nav: false,
    dots: false
});

owl_2.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    smartSpeed: 300,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    nav: false,
    dots: false
});

owl_3.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    smartSpeed: 300,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    nav: false,
    dots: false
});

// STOP AUTOPLAY (without this it wont work, oddly...)
owl_1.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
owl_2.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
owl_3.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');

// START AUTOPLAY SEQUENCIALLY
setTimeout(function(){               
    owl_1.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [10]) // <-- 10 is the delay of scroll
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){               
    owl_2.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [10]) // <-- 10 is the delay of scroll
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function(){               
    owl_3.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [10]) // <-- 10 is the delay of scroll
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Ok, and where do you set the options for each slideshow in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not start autoplay and keep the sliders static.

Comment: see this example: http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html it does start/stop the autoplay using the `trigger` i really think its a way to go

Comment: But it looks like this gets attached to an event, e.g. click.

Comment: In the example, it activates the autoplay with a click on the button "Start autoplay". In your case, you need to start autoplay through a setTimeout. The event you must trigger is the "play.owl.autoplay", and you need to trigger it on a owl_corousel enabled element, like your $('.carousel01')

Comment: Ok, if you add the carousel-option inside ```setTimeout()``` it will delay the initaliztion of the slideshows, not the delay autoplay, which is the objective.

Comment: @TitusQuinn The configuration must be out of setTimeout, see the working code now. i've figured that you need to trigger the stop event first, so the play event will be able to run